# RSpec > Is there a way to run all tests with one command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Is there a command that does this? I've searched but can not find anything

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try this in your terminal window:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

Comment: for idiots like me: make sure you have _spec.rb at the end of each filename or rspec will not be run unless you do some extra config or something

Answer (score 22):

if you are using rspec-rails then you can run using `rake spec`

if you're testing models, use `rake spec:models` (or `rake spec:routing` or `rake spec:controllers`)

if just testing one model, use `rake SPEC=app/models/modelname.rb`

Comment: and if just testing models rake spec:models
  if just testing one model rake SPEC=app/models/modelname.rb

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a `.rspec` file in the root of your project
2. Add the path to where your specs are e.g.

   `--default-path test/spec/`
3. Add the pattern of how your files are named e.g.

   `--pattern ****/*.spec`
4. Run `rspec` and it should pick all your specs and run them :)

`default-path` and `pattern` are simply command line arguments, which means you can also add any other command line argument that rspec takes (can run `rspec --help` to see the available options)

According to https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files you can also put the options in `~/.rspec`, which will make the options available globally. Local `.rspec` file options will override the global options.

Answer (score 4):

For controller test

1. bundle exec rake spec:controllers

For model test

1. bundle exec rake spec:models

For all test

1. bundle exec rake spec

For specific file test do

1. rspec file_name_spec.rb (example rspec spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb)

Answer (score 2):

go to your app directory and run **rspec spec**  or **bundle exec rspec spec**.
use spork to speed your testing...(i kinda say its compulsory)

Comment: the issue with **rake spec** is that it is kinda slow. Its better to use **rspec spec**.