# How to run all Feature test in RSPEC including subfolders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the nested directory like:

```
spec/features/
├── login.rb
└── users
    ├── user_create.rb
    ├── user_edit.rb
    └── user_index.rb
```

using **command** `bundle exec rspec spec/features/login.rb`
will run the login test.

I want to run all the test including the test **inside users folder**.

Something like, `bundle exec rspec spec/features/*.rb`

**I only want to run all the features test.**

Please help!

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec rspec spec/features/`? Seems to work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RSpec > Is there a way to run all tests with one command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203941/rspec-is-there-a-way-to-run-all-tests-with-one-command)

Comment: Oh - for all the tests, just `bundle exec rspec` will do

Comment: Hi @joshua.paling, thanks for answering, but >bundle exec rspec spec/features/ results to No examples found.

Comment: Hi @gmuraleekrishna, I only want to run all the features test.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
 $ bundle exec rspec spec/features/
```

remember to have `_spec.rb` to be in the file name

Comment: Especially the `*_spec.rb` part!

Comment: Hi @gmuraleekrishna, thanks for answering. But the your answer runs all the spec test. I only want to run all the features test.